# extracting .7z file using google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, 7zip, extract

I have this file with .7z prefix and I am trying to extract the content of it with google colab 
I have tried this linux instruction below:

```
!7z img_celeba.7z
```

but unfortunately it give this error below:

> 7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
>   p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,2 CPUs Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.30GHz (306F0),ASM,AES-NI)

Command Line Error:
Unsupported command:
img_celeba.7z

then I tried to install p7zip like below:

```
!apt-get install p7zip-full
!p7zip -d file_name.7z
```

I also get this error

> 7-Zip (a) [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
>   p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,2 CPUs Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.30GHz (306F0),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 734003200 bytes (700 MiB)

Extracting archive: img_celeba.7z
ERROR: img_celeba.7z
img_celeba.7z
Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [7z] archive

ERRORS:
Unexpected end of archive

Can't open as archive: 1
Files: 0
Size:       0
Compressed: 0

what should I do ??...
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am going to close the question with instructions below:
first of all install p7zip using this comand:

```
!apt-get install p7zip-full
```

then try to extract the file with the below inst:

```
!p7zip -d file_name.7z
```

make sure that you provide the parent folder.7z
it worked for me it seems like I were tring to extract a part of the zipped folder 
after some research it turn out the 7zipping partitioning the data in more than one section so all you need to do just refer to the right folder path with the prefix of .7z not its parts

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the command to extract the file. Here is the correct command:

```
!7z x img_celeba.7z
```